# Cannot initialize Row Reordering plugin - rowReordering is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables, row

I'm using jQuery DataTables with [Row Reordering add-on](http://jquery-datatables-row-reordering.googlecode.com/) and for some reason I receive the following error message:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).DataTable(...).rowReordering is not a function

when doing this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $('#demo').html('<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display cell-border"  id="example" ></table>');

        t = $('#example').DataTable({
            "columns": 
            [
                {width: "10%", "className": "ageClass", "title": "Priority",         "data": "priority" },
                {"className": "actionClass", "title": "Action",         "data": "action" },
            ],
            "bPaginate": false,
            "bLengthChange": false,
            "bFilter": false,
            "bInfo": false,
            "bAutoWidth": false,
            "scrollY":        "200px",
            "scrollCollapse": true,
            "paging":         false
        }).rowReordering();;
        // This line is where the console says the error is
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i ++)
        {
            t.row.add(
            {
                priority: i,
                action: i,
            }).draw();
        }    
    });
```

HTML:

```
<div id="demo"> </div>
```

I'm just doing what is described here: 
https://code.google.com/p/jquery-datatables-row-reordering/wiki/Index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **CAUSE**

Original [Row Reordering add-on](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-datatables-row-reordering) is incompatible with DataTables 1.10.

`$(selector).DataTable()` method was added in DataTables 1.10 after [Row Reordering Add-on](http://jquery-datatables-row-reordering.googlecode.com/) has been last updated.

> **SOLUTION**

**For DataTables 1.9**

To use `rowReordering()` you need to initialize your table as `$('#example').dataTable()`, not `$('#example').DataTable()`.

**For DataTables 1.10**

I have [forked the add-on on github](https://github.com/mpryvkin/jquery-datatables-row-reordering) and added support for DataTables 1.10
by using suggestions in the [comments](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-datatables-row-reordering/wiki/Index).

See [jQuery DataTables - Row Reordering](http://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-row-reordering/) article for more details and demonstration.

> **DEMO**

```js
$(document).ready( function () {
   var table = $('#example').DataTable({
      "createdRow": function( row, data, dataIndex ) {
         $(row).attr('id', 'row-' + dataIndex);
      }    
   });

   for(var i = 1; i <= 100; i++){
      table.row.add([ 
         i,
         i + '.2',
         i + '.3',
         i + '.4',
         i + '.5',
         i + '.6'
      ]);
   }  
   
   table.draw();
   
   table.rowReordering();
} );
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>jQuery DataTables</title>  
<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://mpryvkin.github.io/jquery-datatables-row-reordering/1.2.3/jquery.dataTables.rowReordering.js"></script>

</head>
  
<body>
<table id="example" class="display" width="100%">
<thead>
<tr>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Position</th>
  <th>Office</th>
  <th>Age</th>
  <th>Start date</th>
  <th>Salary</th>
</tr>
</thead>

<tfoot>
<tr>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Position</th>
  <th>Office</th>
  <th>Age</th>
  <th>Start date</th>
  <th>Salary</th>
</tr>
</tfoot>

<tbody>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Then I receive this error: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).disableSelection is not a function @ jquery.dataTables.rowReordering.js:202

Comment: @user3262713, `disableSelection()` is a jQuery UI method. Most likely you forgot to load jQuery UI, which Row Reordering add-on requires.

Comment: Thank you. That solved it. But now my row.add function doesn't work anymore.

Comment: @user3262713, use `t.api().row.add` instead.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, but I get this weird syntax error when using the code above with your corrections: [error](http://imgur.com/hEpmdNb)

Comment: It doesn't seem to affect the execution so I'll just ignore it then.

Comment: @user3262713, just checked, this error is definitely related to `rowReordering` being incompatible with DataTables 1.10.

Comment: OK - would you suggest using another version of DataTables?

Comment: @user3262713, see my updated answer for a workaround. I'm working on the example for this and your other question about row numbers.