# Row reordering not works in Datatable jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, datatable

I am use Datatable plugin version - 1.10.15

I want to make my table rows draggable for changing sorting orders and for that i use data tables 'Row reordering' feature but it not works

gives me an error : `Uncaught TypeError: table.rowReordering is not a function`

[This is my work](https://jsfiddle.net/nidhi_akbari_1994/d9gb5hgp/) but not works

I am trying with include all related external sources

My script is

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    "iDisplayLength": 50,
    'createdRow': function(row, data, dataIndex) {
      $(row).attr('id', 'row-' + dataIndex);
    }
  });

  table.rowReordering();
});
```

Please help me to find out where I am going  wrong,by seeing my example

Comment: hey Nidhi, I think you may looking for same like that?[click here](https://editor.datatables.net/examples/extensions/rowReorder)

Comment: `$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    iDisplayLength: 50,
 rowReorder: true,
    createdRow: function(row, data, dataIndex) {
      $(row).attr('id', 'row-' + dataIndex);
    }
  });
});`

Comment: THank you for help and Yes@JaykumarGondaliya I take a hint from here and follow steps but gives me an error.You can see my try.I provide fiddle link in my question

Comment: Thank you@AlivetoDie.I tried your answer.It's make draggable row but not stuck at a position. see [here](https://jsfiddle.net/nidhi_akbari_1994/d9gb5hgp/2/)

Comment: Hey @Nidhi please check [here](https://jsfiddle.net/gyrocode/0308ctqp/)

Comment: It's fantastic that you have provided a fiddle. Now you just need to explain how to recreate your error. I clicked on the table headings and it reordered just fine.

Comment: Thank you @JaykumarGondaliya..Let me try from this fiddle.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I want to reorder table rows.. like jquery sortable feature, Not table headings.

Comment: One More Thing.
**For DataTables 1.9**
To use `rowReordering()` you need to initialize your table as `$('#example').dataTable()`, not `$('#example').DataTable()`
 and must be watch this question i hope you enjoy code.[Link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31438357/cannot-initialize-row-reordering-plugin-rowreordering-is-not-a-function)

Comment: But i m using latest version - 1.10.15 @JaykumarGondaliya

Comment: I looked at jquery sortable. I think you are saying you want to be able to drag and drop rows into different locations?

Comment: Yes, exactly but using datatable row reordering function.@Nick.McDermaid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved my problem using `DataTables 1.10.9, RowReorder 1.0.0`

Here is working fiddle with data table child rows

Simple solution is :

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
  rowReorder: true,
  "iDisplayLength": 50,
});
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/nidhi_akbari_1994/b9ob03pL/)**

Comment: **Great!** Congo @NIdhi

Comment: it's your hard work...I cant do anything. :-)
its Helpful for us. Thanks @Nidhi